# Shared 64bit python installation

Tags: python, 64-bit

I keep a 32bit python26 installation on a shared drive which other computers use to run scripts. These computers have no python interpreter installed.

I tried to put a 64bit python27 on the shared drive and the python.exe fails to start on the remote computers:

[image]

All the remote pc's run 64bit Windows 7. They have a mapped drive "Z" with the python directory and issue commands like:

```
z:\python27\python.exe somescript.py
```

Do I need to drop some extra dll's on the 64bit python27 shared directory to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question. You will need to put `python27.dll` on the shared python folder. This is usually on the `C:\Windows\System32` folder of a local installation.

Answer (score 1):

In future, to avoid this install python on the development machine for "Current User". This will put pythonXX.dll in the install directory, e.g. `C:\Python27` and then you can just copy the whole folder to Z:\ and be done.

When you install python for "All Users" the pythonXX.dll goes into `Windows\System32` (or `Windows\SysWOW64`).